# Getting the error 'conflicting type for function',why?

Tags: c

Here is the below:why it comes out?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void iniStudentLink(struct STUDENT_LINK * L);

int main(){
    return 0;
}

void iniStudentLink(struct STUDENT_LINK * L){
    printf("hello world!\n");
}
```

showing the error : conflicting types for inniStudentLink.

Comment: where `STUDENT_LINK` is defined?

Comment: even though I defined it but it still shows the error

Comment: Yes it is defined, but only locally - twice.  My compilation says "warning: `'struct STUDENT_LINK'` declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
 `void iniStudentLink(struct STUDENT_LINK * L);`"  What compiler and what warnings enabled are you using?  I use "gcc -O0 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -c -fmessage-length=0 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wformat=2 -Wmaybe-uninitialized  ..."

Comment: xcode i have the warning too hah

Comment: Yann - if you get the same warning "parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition", does not that answer the question?  It would be more informative to post all your warnings and error messages _exactly_ - that saves us all time.  I also get "error: conflicting types for 'iniStudentLink'", "note: previous declaration of 'iniStudentLink' was here", "warning: unused parameter 'L' [-Wunused-parameter]".

Comment: Why does your error message contain `inniStudentLink` while the code shown uses `iniStudentLink` twice (the difference being one versus two letters n in the `ini` or `inni` part of the names)?  There's room for suspicion that something wasn't copied accurately — the code shown would be OK as long as the structure type `struct STUDENT_LINK` is at least declared separately from the functions — that could be as simple as a line `struct STUDENT_LINK;` before the function declaration.

Comment: there are several problems with the posted code.  1) the function: `iniStudentLink()` is never called, so it is 'dead code'  2) the struct `StudentLink` is never defined.  3) the function `iniStudentLink()` never references the parameter: `L` 4) a parameter of `L` is meaningless,  A parameter name should indicate `content` or `usage`. the parameter name: 'L' is meaningless even in the current context.

Comment: Note that you don't need the `main` here for the [mcve]...

Comment: ok I now know what's the matters! thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the issues that come out of `gcc` when compiling your code (something it would have been handy to include in your question to make it more complete, that's just advice for the future):

```
testprog.c:3:28: warning: 'struct STUDENT_LINK' declared inside
           parameter list will not be visible outside of
           this definition or declaration
           void iniStudentLink(struct STUDENT_LINK * L);
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
testprog.c:9:28: warning: 'struct STUDENT_LINK' declared inside
           parameter list will not be visible outside of
           this definition or declaration
           void iniStudentLink(struct STUDENT_LINK * L){
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
testprog.c:9:6: error: conflicting types for ‘iniStudentLink’
          void iniStudentLink(struct STUDENT_LINK * L){
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
testprog.c:3:6: note: previous declaration of ‘iniStudentLink’ was here
          void iniStudentLink(struct STUDENT_LINK * L);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

In other words, you are *declaring* two independent instances of the structure, without actually *defining* it<sup>(a)</sup>. The reason they are considered independent is because their scope is limited to the actual function where they are being declared.

You can fix this by *actually* defining it so that the declarations both refer to that definition, such as with (before any other use):

```
struct STUDENT_LINK { int some_data; };
```

In other words, this compiles just fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct STUDENT_LINK { int some_data; };
void iniStudentLink (struct STUDENT_LINK *L);
int main(void) { return 0; }
void iniStudentLink (struct STUDENT_LINK *L){ puts("hi!"); }
```

(although it may should warn you about the fact you don't actually *use* `L` in the function).

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The basic difference between declaring and defining in C is this:

Declaring means declaring that something exists without creating it, such as (in your case) stating that you want to pass a pointer-to-it to a function.

Defining it means literally that, defining what it *is* rather than just *that* it is.

Example declarations are `extern int i;` or `struct xyzzy;` wheras equivalent definitions would be `int i;` and `struct xyzzy { int plugh; };`.

Comment: In fact, it should be enough to simply include a file-scope forward declaration of `struct STUDENT_LINK` before the forward declaration of the function.  It is not necessary to *define* the structure as long as you do not declare instances or access members.